# How to split the content of two columns to many other columns with converting the text to Zeros and Ones in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working on a dataset in a csv format. The number of observations is "22255" and number of variables(columns) is "35".

This is a sample of 2 columns in this dataset which I have (represented in a dataframe):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sector': ['Art & Entertainment',
               'Art & Entertainment',
               'Communication Services',
               'Art & Entertainment',
               'Consumer Discretionary'],
    'region': ['Oregon',
               'SF Bay Area',
               'SF Bay Area',
               'New York City',
               'Los Angeles']
})
```

I am looking to make a preparation of this dataset to be like below:

```
Art & Entertainment   Communication Services   Consumer Discretionary

   1                      0                          0

   1                      0                          0

   0                      1                          0

   1                      0                          0

   0                      0                          1



Portland, Oregon          SF Bay Area                New York City

   1                      0                          0

   0                      1                          0

   0                      1                          0

   0                      0                          1

   0                      0                          0


 Los Angeles

   0

   0

   0

   0

   1
```

This is my code:

```
# Import packages

import pandas as pd


# Read the dataset

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Fall 2020 - Clarkson University/Capestone Analytics project/Internship - SeedStages/Sales dataset - Vijay.csv",
                 engine='python')


ArtEntertainment = []

Technology = []

CommunicationServices = []

ConsumerDiscretionary = []

###


PortlandOregon = []

SFBayArea = []

NewYorkCity = []

LosAngeles = []

###


for line in df['sector']:

    if line == "Art & Entertainment":
        ArtEntertainment.append(1)
    if line != "Art & Entertainment":
        ArtEntertainment.append(0)

    if line == "Communication Services":
        CommunicationServices.append(1)
    if line != "Communication Services":
        CommunicationServices.append(0)

    if line == "Consumer Discretionary":
        ConsumerDiscretionary.append(1)
    if line != "Consumer Discretionary":
        ConsumerDiscretionary.append(0)

for line in df['region']:

    if line == "Portland, Oregon":
        PortlandOregon.append(1)
    if line != "Portland, Oregon":
        PortlandOregon.append(0)

    if line == "SF Bay Area":
        SFBayArea.append(1)
    if line != "SF Bay Area":
        SFBayArea.append(0)

    if line == "New York City":
        NewYorkCity.append(1)
    if line != "New York City":
        NewYorkCity.append(0)

    if line == "Los Angeles":
        LosAngeles.append(1)
    if line != "Los Angeles":
        LosAngeles.append(0)

    
# Collect all the lists into a dataframe

zippedList =  list(zip( ArtEntertainment,CommunicationServices,ConsumerDiscretionary,
                        PortlandOregon,SFBayArea,NewYorkCity,LosAngeles))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(zippedList, columns = ["ArtEntertainment","CommunicationServices","ConsumerDiscretionary",
                        "PortlandOregon","SFBayArea","NewYorkCity","LosAngeles"])

df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, sort=False)
```

I would like to know if there is a possibility to put write the same code in more professional way with less number of code lines. I need really your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your starting data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sector': ['Art & Entertainment',
               'Art & Entertainment',
               'Communication Services',
               'Art & Entertainment',
               'Consumer Discretionary'],
    'region': ['Oregon',
               'SF Bay Area',
               'SF Bay Area',
               'New York City',
               'Los Angeles']
})
```

Your dataframe will look like this:

```
    sector                    region
0   Art & Entertainment       Oregon
1   Art & Entertainment       SF Bay Area
2   Communication Services    SF Bay Area
3   Art & Entertainment New   York City
4   Consumer Discretionary    Los Angeles
```

You're looking for the `pandas.get_dummies` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

The resulting `dummies` dataframe will give you the result you're looking for:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>sector_Art &amp; Entertainment</th>
      <th>sector_Communication Services</th>
      <th>sector_Consumer Discretionary</th>
      <th>region_Los Angeles</th>
      <th>region_New York City</th>
      <th>region_Oregon</th>
      <th>region_SF Bay Area</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want you can remove the `sector_` and `region_` prefixes from the column names as follows:

```
dummies.columns = [col[col.find("_") + 1:] for col in dummies.columns]
```

This finds the index of the first `_` character, adds 1, and then slices the string from that point onward.

Comment: The number of observation for each variable is not 5 observations... It is "22255" observations. I tried to the following, but I have received an error.  df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'sector': df['sector']
    'region': df['region']
})

dummies = pd.get_dummies(df1)

Comment: I would like you to advise me how to fix this error

Comment: Try: dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[['sector', 'region']])

Comment: Thank you so much I fixed the error by df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['sector'])

dummies1 = pd.get_dummies(df1), but if I want to take more than one variable for the same dataframe using  df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['sector'], df['region']), I got [21255 rows x 0 columns]. Do you have any idea in how to do the same processing for more than one variable?